# The shlock -- halachic considerations

Tags: halacha, shabbat, yom-tov, sukkah, boneh-soter

Let's say you bought or [built your own](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/46130/5323) *shlock* (rain cover) for your sukkah.

**What *halachic* concerns are there about operating it on Shabbos/Yom Tov?**
Might there be problems of *boneh* (building)? If the water is set up to fall on grass, could that be an issue of *zoreyah* (planting [here, watering plants])?

Comment: See comments [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/46174/5323)

Comment: See also *The 39 Melachos* by Rabbi Ribiat, page 1067 (vol IV) and on.....will try to form that into an answer, if I can....if you beat me to it you can have it ;)

Comment: You do have to leave it partially open, you can't open it from nothing on yom tov.

Answer (score 1):

Posting from the [comments](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/46130/plans-for-building-a-sukkah-shlock/46174#46174).

The [rama](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.626.3) says there's no problem of building:

> העושה סוכה למטה בבית תחת הגג שהסירו הרעפים אף על פי שנשארו עדיין העצים הדקים שהרעפים מונחים עליהם כשרה: הגה וכן מותר לעשות הסוכה תחת הגגות העשויות לפתוח ולסגור ומותר לסגרן מפני הגשמים ולחזור ולפותחן (מהרי"ל) ואפילו ביום טוב שרי לסוגרן ולפתחן (אגוד' דיומא ומהרי"ו) אם יש להם צירים (ד"ע) שסוגר ופותח בהן ואין בזה לא משום סתירה ובנין אהל בי"ט ולא משום תעשה ולא מן העשוי רק שיזהר שלא ישב תחתיהן כשהן סגורין שאז הסוכה פסולה:One who makes a sukkah in a house below a roof from which the shingles were removed even if the wood or the beams on which the shingles rest remain, it is valid. RAMA: It is also permitted to make a sukkah under the rooves that are made to open and close; and it is permitted to close them due to the rain and then return and open them (Maharil). Even on Yom Tov is is permitted to close and open it (Aggudah d'Yoma; Mahariv). If they have hinges that open and close this does not involve the forbidden [labors] of demolishing or building. One may build a tent [Note: The term ohel is used only for a [structure] that is [at least] ten handbreadths above the ground. Even if it has no walls, it is forbidden to dwell under it.] on Yom Tov and it does not violate 'You shall make, but not from that which is made'. One must be careful to not sit under it when it is closed, for then it is an invalid sukkah